# Alamofire json back "=" not ":"

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Hello I just implement Alamofire and it is working well but the result not json

```
    let UrlString = urlString
    let url = NSURL(string: UrlString)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = hTTPMethod
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let HttpBodyString = httpBody
    let data = HttpBodyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request.HTTPBody = data

    Alamofire.request(request)
       // .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in  
if let JSON = response.result.value {

        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
}
```

it gives me

```
JSON: (
        {
        "Area_ID" = 2;
        "City_ID" = 5;
        "House_Building_No" = 2;
        "House_Floor" = 2;
        "House_QRCode" = 1;
        "Region_ID" = 6;
        "Street_ID" = 2;
    }
)
```

it's not json i want it with : not =  also give me ; not ,

Comment: That's just how dictionaries are formatted when you log them, the raw json has already been converted to an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `response.result.value` variable in Alamofire's responseJSON method is an `NSDictionary`. The printed output you see is the default way of printing NSDictionaries.

If you want to have a string containing JSON, expressed in the standard format (i.e. using ":" between keys and values), then try using the `responseString` method instead.

Alternatively, if you want to have a JSON object, you could use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and do the following:

```
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
    response in  
    if let jsonDictionary = response.result.value {
        let json = JSON(jsonDictionary)
        print(json)
    }
}
```